# Integration Segment with Salesforce, adding an action

Tags: salesforce, twilio, segment-io

[image]All I want to do is,

1. Add Salesforce as destination
2. From the Track Object, get a field
3. Update to Salesforce

I created a custom action
But it does not work

1. everytime it inserts a lead
2. My action is not executed
   What am I doing incorrect?[image]

Below image I am testing to create a case to see if that works.
It throws and error for not including Salesforce:true.
Not sure where to include that

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using the `Create` operation for the action. Instead of creating a new case, you should use an `Update` operation. As the form says:

> If the CRUD Operation is Update an ID field mapping is **required**.

I can't see that you have included an ID field in your field mappings there either. You will need that ID, so that you can update your customer.

Comment: Can you please help me, Its still not working. I have so many questions. @philnash I am unable to attach image to show you here

Comment: I did what you said, its only inserting leads and not updating contacts

Comment: Do you mind sharing your email so that I could send your the issue. Please

Comment: You can edit your question to add more screenshots, that's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: i am attaching more screenshots to my question, please see

Comment: I can’t see any extra screenshots, but the ones you have still show you using a Create action, not an Update. One other thing, I’ve been laid off from Twilio, so I can no longer help here. Hopefully someone else can help from here.

Comment: you had mentioned ID field is required. Where do I get ID field from?? In my Track I dont have an ID that matches with SF Id, are you talking about updating SF ID? Please explain, doesnt mapping mean updating??